# How to pass string from OnStartCommand into OnHandleIntent in an IntentService?

Tags: java, android

Android/Java noob here.  I have a URL that I am discovering in another part of my application.  I am successfully passing that URL as a string into an intent service's OnStartCommand.  I would  then like to make that string containing my URL available to HttpURLConnection residing in a thread in OnHandleIntent as shown below.  How can I get I get the URL within the myUrl string into OnHandleIntent?

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String myUrl;
        myUrl = intent.getExtras().getString("myUrl");

         return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intentNotify) {
        try {
              URL url = new URL("myUrl");
              HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              readStream(con.getInputStream());
              } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be overriding the onStartCommand of an intentservice.
From the [javadoc for onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29)

> You should not override this method for your IntentService. Instead,
>   override onHandleIntent(Intent), which the system calls when the
>   IntentService receives a start request.

Is there a reason why you are not trying to retrieve the extras from the intent passed to onHandleIntent like below?

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String myUrl = intent.getExtras().getString("myUrl");
```

Comment: re: overriding onStartCommand this may be a noob mistake.  I used source>override/implement methods and this is how Eclipse inserted it.  As to the retrieving the extras inside OnHandleIntent when I try this Eclipse says "intent cannot be resolved".  I had looked at a bunch of discussions on how to pass strings into an Intent service and the only method I've managed to get working thus far is to get them inside OnStartCommand (or OnStart which I guess is now deprecated).

Comment: Check the parameter name. I called it "intent" but in your original code you've called it "intentNotify". So yours would be  String myUrl = intentNotify.getExtras().getString("myUrl");

Comment: yes!  That's what I get for copy and pasting another intent service I used previously.  Still learning but typos like this are still biting me way too often.  Thanks very much for taking the time to respond to my question.